# MapKit iOS 16: MKMarkerAnnotationView maker hides image; .markerTintColor = UIColor.clear doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

This is how `MKMarkerAnnotationView` annotations look in iOS 15 in my app.

The markers on the beach only consist of an image no bubble from the `MKMarkerAnnotationView`

[image: AnnotationView consisting only of images]

With iOS 16 beta 3, many but not all images are hidden by the marker bubble; colors appear to be random.

[image: AnnotationView images hidden by bubbles]

`MKMarkerAnnotationView` is set like this:

```
self.glyphImage = myImage
self.glyphText = ""
self.glyphTintColor = UIColor.clear
self.markerTintColor = UIColor.clear
```

I checked in the debugger that this code is executed.

What is the cause and how can I prevent the bubbles from hiding the image?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same issue. This is not fixed in iOS 17. I created an example project (https://github.com/gorkemg/iOS17_MarkerTintColorBug) to demonstrate this issue and filed a bug at Apple (FB12397310). Hopefully, this will be fixed in iOS 17, before it is released. I have no hope for iOS 16, though.

Answer (score 1):

My application primary feature is map and occur this problem too.
The perfect solution that I found is set different identifier for same view class with different annotation type.

Example:

```swift
mapView.register(ERMarkerAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: "BubbleType")
mapView.register(ERMarkerAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: "NonBubbleType")
```

The use `dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier:for:)` to dequeue different type annotation view in different case.

```swift
if needBubble {
    view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "BubbleType",
                                                         for: anno) as? ERMarkerAnnotationView
} else {
    view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "NonBubbleType",
                                                         for: anno) as? ERMarkerAnnotationView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The colors of the bubbles are colors that are used elsewhere in the app.

The following workaround fixes the problem:

in `public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {...}`

replace `mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)` and create a fresh instance of `MKMarkerAnnotationView` or your subclass of `MKMarkerAnnotationView`.

This is a bad workaround since `mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)` is there for a reason, the workaround should have worse performance.

The nature of the workaround suggests a bug in Apples implementation that the internal representation of the bubble is created only once or created only once if `UIColor.clear` is used.

Let's hope Apple fixes this until iOS 16 or someone comes up with a better answer.

App with workaround and iOS 16 beta 3:

[image: Fixed OS 16 version]

Be aware that this workaround only helps in the case where the bubble always is invisible. It does not help in the case if you want the bubble sometimes visible and sometimes invisible vor the same annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 16 every time you set the MKAnnotationView image, the glyph resets. So every time you update your image you also need to clear the glyph.

```
image = [Your Image Here]
glyphTintColor = .clear
glyphText = ""
markerTintColor = .clear
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I created an example project (https://github.com/gorkemg/iOS17_MarkerTintColorBug) to show the issue OP has and filed a bug at Apple (FB12397310). Let me know if you have a fix for this. Thanks.